# Re-render only part of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have SVG map where i want to display some tooltip when user hovers the element:

```
const Tooltip = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className="Tooltip">
            <div className="Tooltip--content">
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tooltip
```

and component

```
const svgField = () => {
    const tooltip = useRef(null);
  // methods

    const FieldWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        position: 'relative',
        /* display */
        overflow: 'hidden',
        '&':{
            'alignItems': "center",
            'justifyContent': "center"
        },

        [theme.breakpoints.up('xs')]: {
            display: 'none'
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
            display: 'flex'
        },
    }));

    return (
        <FieldWrapper >
            <div ref={tooltip} style={{position: 'absolute', display: 'none'}}>
                <Tooltip>
                    {currentTooltipInfo}
                </Tooltip>
            </div>
            <svg className="Field--svg"
                 width={fieldSize[0]}
                 height={fieldSize[1]}
                 sx={{
                     'padding-top':'12px'
                 }}
            >
                <g className="field">
                    {
                        fields.map((d, i) => (
                            <path
                                // 
                                onMouseMove={(e) => handleMouseMove(e, d)}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </g>
            </svg>
        </FieldWrapper >
    )
}
```

now if i use hooks , e.g:

```
 const [tooltipContent, setTooltipContent] = useState(null);
```

and implement handleMouseMove such as:

```
const [tooltipContent, setTooltipContent] = useState(null);


const handleMouseMove = (evt, country) => {
    tooltip.current.style.display = "block";
    tooltip.current.style.left = evt.clientX + 10 + 'px';
    tooltip.current.style.top = evt.clientY + 10 + 'px';
    tooltip.current.style.border="1px solid black";

    setTooltipContent("Some content");
}
```

wouldnt this re-render whole component including SVG ( which is not small ) and thus affect performance while i need only to re-render `tooltip` element?

Is there a way how to rerender only `tooltip` element? I am not proficent in `React` so every piece of information is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid a re-render of the SVG fragment, just extrapolate it in a new Component, and wrap it into `React.memo`, that way it won't re-render if the props it receives do not change.

Just make sure you take that Styled Component, `FieldWrapper`, out of your Component, since Styled Components must not be declared inside the body of a COmponent, or you are going to recreate a new one at each render.

Comment: it seems it still triggers render

Comment: Post your attempt, full code of both components, parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to memoize the SVG component.

```
const svg = useMemo(() => (
    <svg className="Field--svg"
        width={fieldSize[0]}
        height={fieldSize[1]}
        sx={{
            'padding-top': '12px'
        }}
    >
        <g className="field">
            {
                fields.map((d, i) => (
                    <path
                        // 
                        onMouseMove={(e) => handleMouseMove(e, d)}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </g>
    </svg>
), [fieldSize, fields]);
return (
    <FieldWrapper >
        <div ref={tooltip} style={{ position: 'absolute', display: 'none' }}>
            <Tooltip>
                {currentTooltipInfo}
            </Tooltip>
        </div>
        {svg}
    </FieldWrapper >
);
```

This will result in the SVG being recalculated/rerendered only when any of the values in the dependency array change (`fieldSize` or `fields`).